# How to generate tick events from a stopwatch

Tags: c#

I am performing data acquisition (reading temperature, etc.) and I am trying to come up with an alternative to the Windows Forms timer, as it is drifting significantly over long periods of time. I would like to wrap the stopwatch in a class that will fire an event 10 times per second which will trigger collection of a sample (temperature value). I also need to be able to update a chart with current data, although the timing accuracy of collection is more important than keeping the form updated. Data collection can run for a few hours at a time, and from what I understand, the stopwatch would work much better than the windows forms timer considering accuracy is important.

So my question is: What would be a good approach to wrapping the stopwatch to fire an event on a given interval (10 Hz)? Create a thread with a loop that constantly checks the current stopwatch time and fires an event if the stopwatch time is at a desired value? Or is there a different timer that would be better suited for this application?

Comment: There are plenty of questions how to implement high precision timer in Windows... Search first, than edit your post to specify what is acceptable (i.e. get 10 calls a second is easy at 80-120ms intervals and interpolate values is easy with many options, get 10 calls at exactly 100ms interval is very hard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up testing a few different options, and figured the collected info might be useful to someone out there. None the less, I got some funky values at times in the "drift" values (how far away timer values were from from DateTime start and finish times) which I'm guessing is an issue with DateTime accuracy or I screwed something up in the code. None the less, the multimedia timer is clearly the winner for my application.

1000 ms Interval
[image: 1000 ms Interval]

100 ms Interval
[image: 100 ms Interval]

50 ms Interval
[image: 50 ms Interval]

20 ms Interval
[image: 20 ms Interval]

10 ms Interval (The three timers were fighting, so I just went with the Multimedia Timer)
[image: 10 ms Interval]

Form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using TimerTest.Timing.Timers;

namespace TimerTest.Timing
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   A class for testing the performance of different timers
    /// </summary>
    public class TimerTester
    {
        #region Private Fields

        private readonly Chart _outputChart;
        private readonly TextBox _outputTextBox;
        private readonly List<AbstractTimer> _timers = new List<AbstractTimer>();

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        ///   Enable or disable the Timer Tester
        /// </summary>
        public bool Enabled
        {
            get { return _timers.Count > 0 && _timers[0].Enabled; }
            set
            {
                foreach (var timer in _timers)
                {
                    timer.Enabled = value;
                }
                if (value)
                {
                    foreach (var series in OutputChart.Series)
                    {
                        series.Points.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   The chart that the tester is plotting to
        /// </summary>
        public Chart OutputChart
        {
            get { return _outputChart; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   The text box that the tester is writing to
        /// </summary>
        public TextBox OutputTextBox
        {
            get { return _outputTextBox; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        ///   Initializes an instance of TimerTester
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="form"> The form that the timer's tick event should target </param>
        /// <param name="interval"> The timer interval length in ms </param>
        /// <param name="outputChart"> The chart that the tester is plotting to </param>
        /// <param name="outputTextBox"> The text box that the tester is writing to </param>
        public TimerTester(Form form, double interval, Chart outputChart, TextBox outputTextBox)
        {
            _outputChart = outputChart;
            _outputTextBox = outputTextBox;
            //_timers.Add(new SystemTimer(form, interval));
            //_timers.Add(new FormTimer(form, interval));
            _timers.Add(new MultimediaTimer(form, interval));

            // Set Up Events
            foreach (var timer in _timers)
            {
                timer.Tick += TimerOnTick;
            }

            // Set Up Chart
            ChartArea chartArea = OutputChart.ChartAreas[0];
            chartArea.AxisY.Title = "Drift Per Hour [ ms / hr ]";
            chartArea.AxisX.Title = "Time [ min ]";
            chartArea.AxisX.RoundAxisValues();

            // Clear existing series
            OutputChart.Series.Clear();

            foreach (var timer in _timers)
            {
                // Set Up Timer Series
                Series series = OutputChart.Series.Add(timer.Name);
                series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                series.BorderWidth = 2;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Methods

        /// <summary>
        ///   Get the Series associated with a timer
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="timer"> The timer associated with the series </param>
        /// <returns> The timer's series </returns>
        private Series GetSeries(AbstractTimer timer)
        {
            foreach (var series in OutputChart.Series)
            {
                if (series.Name == timer.Name)
                {
                    return series;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Handle tick events
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"> The timer which sent the event </param>
        /// <param name="tickEventArgs"> Event args </param>
        private void TimerOnTick(object sender, TickEventArgs tickEventArgs)
        {
            AbstractTimer timer = (AbstractTimer) sender;

            const int roundTo = 1;
            double dateElapsedSeconds = Math.Round(tickEventArgs.ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds, roundTo);
            double dateElapsedMinutes = tickEventArgs.ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds/60;
            double timerElapsedSeconds = Math.Round(tickEventArgs.TimerElapsedSeconds, roundTo);
            double driftMsPerHour = Math.Round(tickEventArgs.DriftMsPerHour, roundTo);
            double driftMsPerInterval = Math.Round(tickEventArgs.DriftMsPerInterval, roundTo);

            // Plot Timer Data
            Series series = GetSeries(timer);
            series.Points.AddXY(dateElapsedMinutes, driftMsPerHour);

            // Set Up Strings for Output Textbox
            string dateElapsedSecondsString = dateElapsedSeconds.ToString();
            if (!dateElapsedSecondsString.Contains("."))
            {
                dateElapsedSecondsString += ".0";
            }
            string timerElapsedSecondsString = timerElapsedSeconds.ToString();
            if (!timerElapsedSecondsString.Contains("."))
            {
                timerElapsedSecondsString += ".0";
            }
            string driftMsPerHourString = driftMsPerHour.ToString();
            if (!driftMsPerHourString.Contains("."))
            {
                driftMsPerHourString += ".0";
            }
            string driftMsPerIntervalString = driftMsPerInterval.ToString();
            if (!driftMsPerIntervalString.Contains("."))
            {
                driftMsPerIntervalString += ".0";
            }
            string name = timer.Name.PadRight(20, ' ') + " - ";

            OutputTextBox.AppendText(name);
            OutputTextBox.AppendText("Interval: " + tickEventArgs.TimerIntervalsElapsed);
            OutputTextBox.AppendText(" - Timer Elapsed: " + timerElapsedSecondsString);
            OutputTextBox.AppendText(" - DateTime Elapsed: " + dateElapsedSecondsString);
            OutputTextBox.AppendText(" - Ms Drift Per Hour: " + driftMsPerHourString);
            OutputTextBox.AppendText(" - Ms Drift Per Interval: " + driftMsPerIntervalString);
            OutputTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Abstract Timer:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TimerTest.Timing.Timers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An abstract class for defining the structure of a timer
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class AbstractTimer
    {
        #region Public Events

        /// <summary>
        ///   Event Raised when the Timer has elapsed
        /// </summary>
        public abstract event EventHandler<TickEventArgs> Tick;

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        ///   Determines whether or not the timer is enabled
        /// </summary>
        public abstract bool Enabled { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///   The form which the timer will invoke the Tick event on
        /// </summary>
        public abstract Form Form { get; }

        /// <summary>
        ///   The length of the interval in milliseconds
        /// </summary>
        public abstract double IntervalLength { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///   The number of intervals that have elapsed
        /// </summary>
        public abstract int IntervalsElapsed { get; }

        /// <summary>
        ///   The name of the timer
        /// </summary>
        public abstract string Name { get; }

        /// <summary>
        ///   The time at which the timer started
        /// </summary>
        public abstract DateTime StartTime { get; }

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        /// <summary>
        ///   Star the timer
        /// </summary>
        public abstract void Start();

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempt to stop the timer
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>True if the timer was successfully stopped, false if not</returns>
        public abstract bool Stop();

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Tick Event Args:

```
using System;

namespace TimerTest.Timing.Timers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Event Arguments for Tick Events
    /// </summary>
    public class TickEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        #region Private Fields

        private readonly DateTime _currentTime;
        private readonly DateTime _startTime;
        private readonly double _timerIntervalLength;
        private readonly int _timerIntervalsElapsed;

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        ///   The current time when the TickEventArgs were created
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime CurrentTime
        {
            get { return _currentTime; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   The average number of milliseconds that the the timer has drifted away from the actual time each hour. 
        ///   A negative value indicates that the timer is running slower than the set interval, 
        ///   and a positive value indicates that the timer is running faster than the set interval
        /// </summary>
        public double DriftMsPerHour
        {
            get { return (DriftSecondsTotal*1000*60*60)/ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   The average number of milliseconds that the the timer has drifted away from the actual time on each interval. 
        ///   A negative value indicates that the timer is running slower than the set interval, 
        ///   and a positive value indicates that the timer is running faster than the set interval
        /// </summary>
        public double DriftMsPerInterval
        {
            get { return (DriftSecondsTotal*1000)/(ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds*(1000/TimerIntervalLength)); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   The average number of milliseconds that the the timer has drifted away from the actual time each minute. 
        ///   A negative value indicates that the timer is running slower than the set interval, 
        ///   and a positive value indicates that the timer is running faster than the set interval
        /// </summary>
        public double DriftMsPerMinute
        {
            get { return (DriftSecondsTotal*1000*60)/(ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   The average number of milliseconds that the the timer has drifted away from the actual time each second. 
        ///   A negative value indicates that the timer is running slower than the set interval, 
        ///   and a positive value indicates that the timer is running faster than the set interval
        /// </summary>
        public double DriftMsPerSecond
        {
            get { return (DriftSecondsTotal*1000)/ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   The total number of seconds that the timer has drifted away from the actual time. 
        ///   A negative value indicates that the timer is running slower than the set interval, 
        ///   and a positive value indicates that the timer is running faster than the set interval
        /// </summary>
        public double DriftSecondsTotal
        {
            get { return TimerElapsedSeconds - ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   The actual number of seconds elapsed
        /// </summary>
        public TimeSpan ElapsedTime
        {
            get { return CurrentTime - StartTime; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   The time that the timer started
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime StartTime
        {
            get { return _startTime; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   The number of seconds elapsed by the timer
        /// </summary>
        public double TimerElapsedSeconds
        {
            get { return TimerIntervalsElapsed*TimerIntervalLength/1000; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   The interval length of the timer
        /// </summary>
        public double TimerIntervalLength
        {
            get { return _timerIntervalLength; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   The number of intervals elapsed by the timer
        /// </summary>
        public int TimerIntervalsElapsed
        {
            get { return _timerIntervalsElapsed; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        ///   Initializes an instance of TickEventArgs
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="startTime"> The time that the timer started </param>
        /// <param name="timerIntervalsElapsed"> The number of intervals elapsed by the timer </param>
        /// <param name="timerIntervalLength"> The interval length of the timer </param>
        /// <param name="currentTime"> The current time when the TickEventArgs were created </param>
        public TickEventArgs(DateTime startTime, int timerIntervalsElapsed,
                             double timerIntervalLength, DateTime currentTime)
        {
            _startTime = startTime;
            _timerIntervalsElapsed = timerIntervalsElapsed;
            _timerIntervalLength = timerIntervalLength;
            _currentTime = currentTime;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Multimedia Timer:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TimerTest.Timing.Timers
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   A wrapper for a winmm.dll timer
    /// </summary>
    public class MultimediaTimer : AbstractTimer
    {
        #region Public Events

        /// <summary>
        ///   Event Raised when the Timer has elapsed
        /// </summary>
        public override event EventHandler<TickEventArgs> Tick;

        #endregion

        #region Private Fields

        private bool _enabled;
        private readonly Form _form;
        private double _intervalLength;
        private int _intervalsElapsed;
        private DateTime _startTime;

        private UInt32 _timerId;

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public override bool Enabled
        {
            get { return _enabled; }
            set
            {
                if (value)
                {
                    Start();
                }
                else
                {
                    Stop();
                }
            }
        }

        public override Form Form
        {
            get { return _form; }
        }

        public override double IntervalLength
        {
            get { return _intervalLength; }
            set { _intervalLength = value; }
        }

        public override int IntervalsElapsed
        {
            get { return _intervalsElapsed; }
        }

        public override string Name
        {
            get { return "MultiMedia Timer"; }
        }

        public override DateTime StartTime
        {
            get { return _startTime; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        ///   Initializes an instance of MultimediaTimer
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="form"> The form which the timer will invoke the Tick event on </param>
        /// <param name="intervalLength"> The length of the interval in milliseconds </param>
        public MultimediaTimer(Form form, double intervalLength)
        {
            _form = form;
            _intervalLength = intervalLength;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        public override void Start()
        {
            if (Enabled)
                return;

            uint interval = Convert.ToUInt32(Math.Round(_intervalLength, 0));
            _timerId = Winmm.Start(interval, TimerCallback);
            _startTime = DateTime.Now;

            _enabled = true;
        }

        public override bool Stop()
        {
            if (Enabled)
            {
                bool stopped = Winmm.Stop(_timerId);
                _enabled = !stopped;
                return stopped;
            }
            return false;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Methods

        private void TimerCallback(int id, int msg, IntPtr user, int dw1, int dw2)
        {
            _intervalsElapsed++;
            if (Enabled)
            {
                TriggerTick();
            }
        }

        private void TriggerTick()
        {
            DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

            _form.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
                                                  {
                                                      TickEventArgs tickEventArgs = new TickEventArgs(StartTime,
                                                                                                      IntervalsElapsed,
                                                                                                      IntervalLength,
                                                                                                      currentTime);
                                                      if (Tick != null)
                                                      {
                                                          Tick(this, tickEventArgs);
                                                      }
                                                  });
        }

        #endregion

        #region Nested Classes

        /// <summary>
        ///   A static wrapper for Winmm.dll
        /// </summary>
        public static class Winmm
        {
            #region Static Private Fields

            /// <summary>
            ///   The Event Type
            /// </summary>
            private const int _EVENT_TYPE = _TIME_PERIODIC; // + 0x100;  // TIME_KILL_SYNCHRONOUS causes a hang ?!

            private const int _TIME_PERIODIC = 1;

            /// <summary>
            ///   The Event Handler for the timer
            /// </summary>
            private static TimerEventHandler _mHandler;

            #endregion

            #region Static Public Methods

            /// <summary>
            ///   Start
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="interval"> The interval between ticks in ms </param>
            /// <param name="timerCallBack"> The delegate to call on each tick </param>
            /// <returns> The Timer ID </returns>
            public static UInt32 Start(uint interval, TimerEventHandler timerCallBack)
            {
                timeBeginPeriod(1);
                _mHandler = timerCallBack;
                return timeSetEvent(interval, 0, _mHandler, IntPtr.Zero, _EVENT_TYPE);
            }

            /// <summary>
            ///   Stop a timer with a given ID
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="mTimerId"> The Timer ID of the timer to stop </param>
            /// <returns> </returns>
            public static bool Stop(UInt32 mTimerId)
            {
                UInt32 err = timeKillEvent(mTimerId);

                if (err != (int) Mmresult.Mmsyserr_Noerror)
                    return false;

                timeEndPeriod(1);
                // Ensure callbacks are drained
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                return true;
            }

            #endregion

            #region Static Private Methods

            [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
            private static extern int timeBeginPeriod(int msec);

            [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
            private static extern int timeEndPeriod(int msec);

            /// <summary>
            ///   The multi media timer stop function
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="uTimerId"> timer id from timeSetEvent </param>
            /// <remarks>
            ///   This function stops the timer
            /// </remarks>
            [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            private static extern UInt32 timeKillEvent(UInt32 uTimerId);

            /// <summary>
            ///   A multi media timer with millisecond precision
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="msDelay"> One event every msDelay milliseconds </param>
            /// <param name="msResolution"> Timer precision indication (lower value is more precise but resource unfriendly) </param>
            /// <param name="handler"> delegate to start </param>
            /// <param name="userCtx"> callBack data </param>
            /// <param name="eventType"> one event or multiple events </param>
            /// <remarks>
            ///   Dont forget to call timeKillEvent!
            /// </remarks>
            /// <returns> 0 on failure or any other value as a timer id to use for timeKillEvent </returns>
            [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "timeSetEvent")]
            private static extern UInt32 timeSetEvent(UInt32 msDelay, UInt32 msResolution, TimerEventHandler handler,
                                                      IntPtr userCtx, UInt32 eventType);

            #endregion

            #region Public Delegates

            /// <summary>
            ///   The Timer's Event Handler
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="id"> </param>
            /// <param name="msg"> </param>
            /// <param name="user"> </param>
            /// <param name="dw1"> </param>
            /// <param name="dw2"> </param>
            public delegate void TimerEventHandler(int id, int msg, IntPtr user, int dw1, int dw2);

            #endregion

            #region Public Enumerators

            /// <summary>
            ///   Possible Return Values
            /// </summary>
            public enum Mmresult : uint
            {
                /// <summary>
                ///   No Error
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Noerror = 0,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Error
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Error = 1,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Bad Device ID
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Baddeviceid = 2,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Not Enabled
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Notenabled = 3,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Allocated
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Allocated = 4,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Invalid Handle
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Invalhandle = 5,

                /// <summary>
                ///   No Driver
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Nodriver = 6,

                /// <summary>
                ///   No Mem
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Nomem = 7,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Not Supported
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Notsupported = 8,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Bad Error Number
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Baderrnum = 9,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Invalid Falg
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Invalflag = 10,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Invalid Parameter
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Invalparam = 11,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Handle Busy
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Handlebusy = 12,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Invalid Alias
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Invalidalias = 13,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Baddb
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Baddb = 14,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Key Not Found
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Keynotfound = 15,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Read Error
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Readerror = 16,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Write Error
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Writeerror = 17,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Delete Error
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Deleteerror = 18,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Value Not Found
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Valnotfound = 19,

                /// <summary>
                ///   No Driver CB
                /// </summary>
                Mmsyserr_Nodrivercb = 20,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Bad Format
                /// </summary>
                Waverr_Badformat = 32,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Still Playing
                /// </summary>
                Waverr_Stillplaying = 33,

                /// <summary>
                ///   Unprepared
                /// </summary>
                Waverr_Unprepared = 34
            }

            #endregion
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Stopwatch` class doesn't push anything.  It just sits there and tells you how much time has elapsed when you ask it.  To ask it how much time has elapsed, you would need an event.  I would suggest using a `Timers.Timer` to see if that's any better and, if not, then look at using a high-resolution timer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx